# Search button using time vba

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to create a search button that, when a time is entered in cell (B10) and button pressed, will copy values to the sheet. Tried a few tutorials but I keep doing something wrong.

Search function is on sheet1 and all my data is on sheet2. Date and time (m/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss) are entered in cell B10 and info should be copy/pasted into cells D10:I10. Time on sheet2 is in A, while the data I want is B to G. The search should only return one row of values.

What did I do wrong in my code?

```
Sub search()

Dim erow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim count As Integer

lastrow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 2 To lastrow

If Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(x, 1) = Sheet1.Range("B10") Then
Sheet1.Range("D10") = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(x, 2)
Sheet1.Range("E10") = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(x, 3)
Sheet1.Range("F10") = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(x, 4)
Sheet1.Range("G10") = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(x, 5)
Sheet1.Range("H10") = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(x, 6)
Sheet1.Range("I10") = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(x, 7)
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `Rows` in `Rows.Count` is (implicitly) referring to whatever worksheet is active. If that's not `Sheet2` and your code works, then it's out of sheer luck. Best qualify that `Rows` call with the worksheet it's meant to be looking at. Also you should fetch worksheet references from the `Worksheets` collection, since the `Sheets` collection can contain charts and other non-worksheet sheet types.

Comment: Your `For` loop needs a `Next` token to terminate.

Answer (score 1):

Is Sheet1 declared as a variable? I dont see anywhere that you are setting it. Try this instead:

```
Sub search()

    Dim erow As Long

    Dim wbTarget as Workbook
    Dim wsTarget as Worksheet

    Dim wsSource as Worksheet

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim count As Integer

    Dim r as Range

    Set wbTarget = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set wsSource = wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet2")

    lastrow = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 2 To lastrow

        If wsSource.Cells(x, 1) = wsTarget.Range("B10") Then
            Set r = wsSource.Cells(x, 2).Resize(8, 1)
            wsTarget.Range("D10:I10").Value = r.Value
            Set r = Nothing
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I dont know why some of the code is red, but this should work.

Comment: Fixed the next. I had no clue about CodeNames so thanks for pointing that out. That actually makes a lot of sense and is definitely better than using SheetNames when working with files where sheet names are prone to being edited. I'll definitely be using CodeNames in the future!

Comment: Thanks, I ended up replacing the set r code though. It seems to just repeat the value from column 2 multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub search2()
    Dim myCell As Range, foundCell As Range

    Set myCell = Worksheets("Sheet01").Range("B10")
    With Worksheets("Sheet02")
        Set foundCell = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)).Find(what:=myCell.Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlWhole) '<--| try and find wanted date/time
        If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then myCell.Offset(, 2).Resize(, 6).Value = foundCell.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 6).Value '<--| if found then copy its adjacent 6 columns to Sheet1 "D10:E10" range
    End With
End Sub
```